# Let $n>2k$. Show that the $k$ element subsets of an $n$ set can be uniquely extended to $k+1$ sets.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

The question is essentially just the title.

Clarification: Here is an example with $n=3$ and $k=1$:
$k$-set $\to$ $k+1$-set; $1\to12$, $2\to23$, $3\to13$.

Since $n>2k$, I know that there are enough $k+1$-sets for a mapping between the two to exist, but I am struggling to see how I know that the mapping ensures that the sets are extended.

I know that each $k$-set can be extended in $n-k$ different ways, but I don't know if it is true that there is a way of extending each $k$-set such that each set always has an available way to extend.

I was told that this problem uses Hall's Matching theorem, but that is a result from graph theory and I do not really know how to apply it here.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Perhaps a numerical example would clarify matters.  Suppose $k=1, n=3$  Can you illustrate your question in that case?

Comment: I guess it is something like "for any collection of distinct $k$-element subsets $a_1, \ldots, a_m$ there exist collection of distinct $k + 1$-element subsets $b_1, \ldots, b_m$ s.t. $a_i \subset b_i$". Is it what you are asking?

Comment: I think the problem is to show that there is an injective mapping $f$ from the $k$-subsets of $[1,\ldots, n]$ to the $k+1$-subsets of $[1,\ldots,n]$ such that $A \subset f(A)$ for every $A$.

Comment: Robert is correct. I added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the bipartite graph with vertices consisting of $k$-sets and $(k+1)$ sets, with an edge between $A$ (a $k$-set) and $B$ (a $(k+1)$-set) iff $A \subset B$. As you've said, each $k$-set $A$ has degree $n-k$. Can you now see how to use Hall?